# .NET Exception Kills VB6 App

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop

I have a VB6 app. It's calling .NET code. The .NET code occasionally throws an Exception by design.

VB6 has an On Error Goto Statement in the Function calling the .NET code. When .NET throws an exception, the VB6 code should handle the error (in the Goto block), write the Err.Description to a log, and calls Err.Clear, and should proceed along it's way.

This works fine and as expected (as described above) when running the VB6 app from Visual Studio 6.0. When I run the VB6 app from a compiled exe, I see the expected error in my VB6 log file...but after the error occurs, the VB6 app hangs for a moment, then crashes unexpectedly. There isn't even an APPCRASH report in the Event Viewer.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Any error messages, or does the app just disappear?

Comment: Just disappears. Nothing in event viewer. However, I do see that VB6 has logged the thrown .NET error correctly right before the crash.

Comment: What interface is there between the .NET and VB6 app? I've seen similar issues when I screwed up COM interfaces or general stack corruption causing one or the other to break.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like a threading issue, even though you are saying that it's not the case.  I'd start with a tool like Process Explorer and monitor what threads get created when the call is made. It could be inadvertent.

Secondly, I'd log the successful return from the .NET code as well - it is possible that the error occurs in your code.

Comment: When .NET encounters no error, there's no problem (and we already do log that event as well). When .NET throws and VB6 catches, VB6 logs the error no problem too...but at some point immediately after logging the error and calling Err.Clear, VB6 dies, abruptly

Comment: If it were a .NET threading exception terminating via an unhandled exception, wouldn't I see something in Event Viewer Application log about an unhandled CLR exception?

Comment: @JeffN825 Do the following.  Add a .config file to your VB6 app.  E.g. create a file called MyVb6App.exe.config.  In this file, place the following: `<configuration><startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
<requiredRuntime version="v2.0.50727" safemode="true"/>
</startup></configuration>` or whatever your .NET framework is.  Let me know how it went.